# Como fazer pequena animação com js

Tags: javascript, html

Olá, gostaria de fazer uma pequena animação responsiva para mostrar informações.

Por exemplo, tenho esse retangulo:

```html
<div id="mainDiv" >
    <div id="Rectangle" style="width: 200px; height: 300px; background: #3c9e43; margin-left: 20px; margin-top: 30px; float: left;"></div>
</div>
```

E quando passar o mouse por cima subisse uma pequena div mostrando informações, e quando o mouse sair aconteceria uma animação dele abaixando, desta forma:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu gostaria de saber uma forma para chegar a isso.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode deixar uma `div` com os textos escondidas, e exibir quando o mouse passar por cima, usando [transitions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Transitions/Using_CSS_transitions) em css para , algo como:

```css
#content {
  position: relative;
  background-color: green;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;
}

#content:hover > #info {
  bottom: 0;
  visibility: visible;
}

#content #info {
  background: brown;
  width: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -30px;
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.7s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.7s ease-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.7s ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.7s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.7s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <div id="info">
    Informação 1<br/> 
    Informação 1
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Adicione `overflow: hidden;` a `#content` no CSS e terá um resultado bem mais agradável.

Comment: Perfeito, obrigado @AndersonCarlosWoss.